# Determinant of a nonfree module

Tags: algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, modules, determinant, ringed-spaces

Is there a definition of a determinant which can be applied to a module with no basis?

We can produce a module with noncommutative rings, without knowing a basis for these rings, i.e. without units. Can we assign an "area" value to a field extension of the entire family of rings with the unit of the extension, and without establishing a basis surrounding that unit?

Follow up question, if there is such an area-finding function of a general module, will it persist for modules $M,N$ that det$(MN)$$=$(det$M$)(det$N$) and det$(NM)$$=$(det$N$)(det($M$)?

Comment: If you have a commutative domain which is locally a UFD, the usual way of assigning a determinant of a finitely generated module $M$ is as follows. If rank of $M$ is $r$, define $\det M$ to be the double dual of the $r^{\mathrm{th}}$ exterior of $M$, which is a projective module of rank one. In your last part, what do you mean by $MN$ for two modules $M,N$?

Comment: The question is regarding noncommutative rings, and $MN$ can be the tensor product, or any product that produces a module.